# fscanf_s reading random lines from text file out of order and only reading 4 lines

Tags: c

I have a data set I am trying to go through in order, however fscanf_s() and a function I wrote that uses fgetc() both only read 4 lines that are out of order in my data set. I terminate the loop that is utilizing the values when either 1 of my data sets is empty or when fscanf_s() or my personal function returns EOF.

I tried testing what line it cancels on but its random every time. I looked for some similar problems but most of them just said to use fgets or fgetc and then parse which I am already doing with my personal function.

```
double update_weights_v2(LOGISTIC_MODEL hModel, FILE* data_input, FILE* data_output) {
    Model* pModel = (Model*)hModel;
    int status1, status2;
    double X, Y, error = 0, prediction, W1_deriv = 0, W2_deriv = 0;
    int n = 0;

    //X = parse_data_double(data_input, &status1);
    //Y = parse_data_double(data_output, &status2);

    status1 = fscanf_s(data_input, "%[^\n]lf", &X);
    status2 = fscanf_s(data_output, "%[^\n]lf", &Y);

    while (status1 != EOF && status2 != EOF) {
        prediction = pModel->activation(X, pModel->W1, pModel->W2);
        error = Y - prediction;

        // df/dW1 = 1/n SUM[1->n](-2*Xi * (error))
        W1_deriv += (X * error * pModel->rate);
        // df/dW2 = 1/n SUM[1->n](-2 * (error))
        W2_deriv += (error*pModel->rate);

        // Read next data entry
        //X = parse_data_double(data_input, &status1);
        //Y = parse_data_double(data_output, &status2);
        status1 = fscanf_s(data_input, "%[^\n]lf", &X);
        status2 = fscanf_s(data_output, "%[^\n]lf", &Y);
        n++;
        printf("Input: %.5lf\nOutput: %.5lf\nGuess: %.5lf\nError: %.5lf\nWeight[1]: %.5lf\nWeight[2]: %.5lf\n*************************************************************\n", X, Y, prediction, error, pModel->W1, pModel->W2);
    }
    rewind(data_input);
    rewind(data_output);
    return error;
}
```

I expected this code to iterate through the entire data set, then reset the file so that its at the first character after every full run through the data set.

Comment: The format specifier `%[^\n]lf` is incorrect for a `double` variable. Are you reading a string, or a floating point value? Please show a short example of the data you are reading. Please check the warnings given by the compiler.

Comment: Warning C4477: 'scanf_s' : format string '%[^\n]' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double *'

Comment: You will also want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong). You are essentially doing the same thing.

Comment: sorry I posted code after I was trying %[^\n]lf it still has issues as %lf

Answer (score 1):

While you have not provided a [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the immediate problem with your code after you fix the `"%[^\n]"` and make it `"%lf"`, is that you are conditioning the end of your read loop on `status1 != EOF && status2 != EOF`. Neither will be `EOF` until after you invoke *Undefined Behavior* by attempting to `printf` the `X, Y` values after `EOF` is reached.

Further, conditioning your loop on `EOF` ignores any *matching* or *input* failure that may result before `EOF` is reached. Instead, you always validate whether `scanf` (`f_scanf` in you case) succeeds or fails based on the *Number Of Successful Conversions*, i.e. the numeric value returned. Which is why you were referred to [Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) in the comments.

It is far better to control your read loop based on the numeric returns, e.g.

```
    while (fscanf_s (data_input, "%lf", &X) == 1 &&
            fscanf_s(data_output, "%lf", &Y) == 1) {
```

or simply loop continually until either fails, e.g.

```
while (1) {
    ...
    status1 = fscanf_s (data_input, "%lf", &X);
    if (status1 != 1) {
        if (status1 == EOF) {
            fputs ("status1-EOF\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        else if (status1 == 0) {
            fputs ("matching or input failure.\n", stderr);
            /* matching or input failure occurred,
             * handle as appropriate (clear to '\n' or break).
             */
        }
    }
```

Given what it looks like you are trying to accomplish, you can go with something similar to the following:

```
double update_weights_v2 (LOGISTIC_MODEL hModel, 
                            FILE* data_input, FILE* data_output) 
{
    Model* pModel = (Model*)hModel;
    double X, Y, error = 0, prediction, W1_deriv = 0, W2_deriv = 0;
    int n = 0;

    while (fscanf_s (data_input, "%lf", &X) == 1 &&
            fscanf_s(data_output, "%lf", &Y) == 1) {
        prediction = pModel->activation(X, pModel->W1, pModel->W2);
        error = Y - prediction;

        W1_deriv += (X * error * pModel->rate);
        W2_deriv += (error*pModel->rate);

        n++;

        printf ("Input: %.5lf\nOutput: %.5lf\nGuess: %.5lf\nError: %.5lf\n"
                "Weight[1]: %.5lf\nWeight[2]: %.5lf\n"
                "***********************************************************\n",
                X, Y, prediction, error, pModel->W1, pModel->W2);
    }
    rewind(data_input);
    rewind(data_output);

    return error;
}
```

(**note:** your `rewind()` at the end will mask the stream state set within the function -- that may be what you want, it can also mask a problem in the data file that will just bite you again on your next call to `update_weights_v2()`)

To help further we will need [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

While there have been many helpful answers, the fix to this was a problem with a line that wasn't showing in vs code. For whatever reason, I wasn't able to view a line that was supposed to limit the amount of outputs the program could show so that it wouldn't spam the console with every single guess my model made. I reloaded vs code after an update and the line was back. I'm not sure why this happened but it makes sense now.

Thank you.